# Typedef a member type of a template

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a formulation like this:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct SomeLibraryClass
{
     using Foo = A;
     using Bar = B;
};
```

Now I want to use it but rename it since conceptually the usage is different.

```
template <typename A, typename B>
using quaz = SomeLibraryClass<A, B>;
```

However, if I want to get bar, it's still `quaz::bar`. But say I want `quaz::bar` to be `quaz::foobar` instead. Is this possible? Why or why not?

I cannot use inheritance. It silently breaks the code.

Comment: More examples would be nice, I have no idea what you mean

Comment: that damned inheritance, running around, breaking stuff silently!

Comment: could you use a template param that is the name of the struct?

Comment: Why don't you have `using quazfoobar = quaz::bar`? What is the advantage you get from having `quaz::foobar` over `quazfoobar`?

Comment: Your last sentence is rather cryptic. How does inheritance silently break code?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add or remove members, or change the name of a member of a class that is already defined. All you can do is define a new class.